# build table with jquery template plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I feel helpless. I'd like to build a table with jquery template plugin and then fill table with the data from the response which looks like this:

```
[
     [
        {Row:0,Col:0},
        {Row:0,Col:1},
        {Row:0,Col:2},
        {Row:0,Col:3},
        {Row:0,Col:4},
        {Row:0,Col:5},
        {Row:0,Col:6}
     ],
     [
        {Row:1,Col:0},
        {Row:1,Col:1},
        {Row:1,Col:2},
        {Row:1,Col:3},
        {Row:1,Col:4},
        {Row:1,Col:5},
        {Row:1,Col:6}
     ]
]
```

So the table is supposed to be with 2 rows and 7 columns in each row.

Here's the code I stuck with:

```
$('#trTemplate').tmpl(result.d).appendTo('#containerTable');

<script id="trTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each $data}}
        {{if $index < 2}}
            <tr>
                {{tmpl($value) "#tdTemplate"}}
            </tr>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="tdTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each $data}}
        <td>${Col}</td>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<table id="containerTable">
</table>
```

I tried different approaches, changed the look of the data source which works fine, tried to build table without template, but I really need to know how to build a table with having such data source and using templates? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your needs, here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/cEvJs/

One thing to remember is that if you pass an array into the template function it automatically evaluates it for each item in the array.  So, your template can be as simple as:

```
<script id="trTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
       <tr>
            {{each $data}}
                 <td>${Col}</td>
            {{/each}}
       </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: very good solution. thanks a lot guys for your help! now I see how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following templates:

```
<script id="tmpRow" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        {{each $data}}
          {{tmpl "#tmpCell", this}}
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="tmpCell" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <td>${Col}</td>
</script>
```

You will be able to build up your table with the following templ call.

```
var $rowTemplate = $("#tmpRow").template("tmpRow");
$("table tbody").append($.tmpl($rowTemplate, data));
```

Example on [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/dXY89/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //__________________Compile Templates ____________________________
    $("#trTemplate").template("trTemplate");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = "[[{Row:0,Col:0},{Row:0,Col:1},{Row:0,Col:2},{Row:0,Col:3},{Row:0,Col:4},{Row:0,Col:5},{Row:0,Col:6}],[{Row:1,Col:0},{Row:1,Col:1},{Row:1,Col:2},{Row:1,Col:3},{Row:1,Col:4},{Row:1,Col:5},{Row:1,Col:6}]]";
        $.tmpl("trTemplate", eval(data)).appendTo("#containerTable");
    });
</script>

<script id="trTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        {{each $data}}
             <td>${Col}</td>
        {{/each}}
   </tr>
</script>

<table id="containerTable">
</table>
```